# Надо ли ставить запятую в случае усиления?

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые умники и умницы, прошу вас прояснить вопрос.
Есть предложение:

> Вы можете узнать больше информации о деятельности нашей компании, просто позвонив нам!

Запятая после слова "компании" вроде как стоит правильно! Но не могу пропустить ни как, как будто глаз режет. Может ли не ставиться запятая в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

> Вы можете узнать больше информации о деятельности нашей компании,
>   просто позвонив нам!

Я бы написал так:

*Вы можете **получить** больше информации о деятельности нашей компании, просто...*

или так (выкинув слово "информации"):

*Вы можете узнать больше о деятельности нашей компании, просто...*

Answer (score 1):

"Узнать больше информации"?! Это же кошмар. Просто "узнать больше"

Answer (score 0):

Запятая поставлена верна! Она отделяет деепричастие "позвонив".

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Авторская мысль выражена правильно, также верно поставлена запятая:

"Вы можете узнать больше информации о деятельности нашей компании, просто позвонив нам!"

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

К деепричастиям могут быть отнесены ЧАСТИЦЫ И СОЮЗЫ (СОЮЗНЫЕ СЛОВА), которые обособляются вместе с деепричастными оборотами, не отделяясь от них запятыми, например:

Она сидела молча, только слегка улыбаясь.Я вцепился обеими руками в края топчана, словно боясь сорваться с него.